# Django and ajax instead of jquery popupdivs

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I am working on a django recipe website and one of the pages is currently setup using 
hidden divs and I believe it is slowing the webpage down quite a bit.

Let me explain further:

I have a page consisting of 6 recipes. each of these recipes is a link and when you click that link
it activates a jquery function that turns a hidden div into a div that popups the content over the content container with a opaque black background. The problem with this is that all 6 divs are hidden behind the content container and I believe this is slowing down the sites performance a noticeable amount (especially since I will also be loading comments and perhaps pictures etc).

What i would like to do is use ajax to fetch the information only when necessary instead of having all of the content loaded. (including comments and all information specific to a recipe)

perhaps instead of 6 popup divs i could have just one and load the relevant recipe content into that div.

I am new to ajax and was wondering how exactly this would be implemented with django.

here is the template:

```
<div id="recipe_cont">
    {% for recipe in recipe_list %}
    <div id="recipe">
        <div id="button{{ forloop.counter }}">  //creates 6 buttons because my page is paginated 6 objects to a page    
        <h4>{{ recipe.name }}</h4>
        <h5>{{ recipe.author }}</h5>
        <h5>Prep Time: {{ recipe.prep_time }} minutes</h5>
        </div>
                <h6><a href="/addrecipe/{{ recipe.id }}">Add Recipe</a>
            <a href="/removerecipe/{{ recipe.id }}">Remove Recipe</a></h6>

        <div id="popupContact{{ forloop.counter }}" class="popup">// this is the information I want to use ajax to retrieve and place into the popup div
                        <a id="popupContactClose{{ forloop.counter }}" style="cursor:pointer;float:right;">x</a>
                    <h1>{{ recipe.name }}
                    </h1>
                        <h3>{{ recipe.author }}</h3>
                        <p id="contactArea">
                        Ingredients: {{ recipe.ingredients }}
                        <br/><br/>
                        Steps: {{ recipe.steps }}
                        </p>
                     <br/><br/><br/><br/>
                        <br/>

                        {% get_comment_form for recipe as form %}
                        <table>
                    <form action="{% comment_form_target %}" method="post">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        {{ form }}
                        <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Post" />
                        <input type="submit" name="preview" value="Preview" />
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                        </form>
                        </table>
                        {% for comment in comment_list %}
                        <a name="c{{ comment.id }}">comment</a>
                        {% endfor %}
            </div>
        <div id="backgroundPopup">
                </div>      
    </div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

here is the relevant jquery code: this code is just to demonstrate how the popup div works - don't think you really need to see this

```
/***************************/
//@Author: Adrian "yEnS" Mato Gondelle
//@website: www.yensdesign.com
//@email: yensamg@gmail.com
//@license: Feel free to use it, but keep this credits please!                  
/***************************/

//SETTING UP OUR POPUP
//0 means disabled; 1 means enabled;
var popupStatus = 0;

//loading popup with jQuery magic!
function loadPopup($contact_selector){
    //loads popup only if it is disabled
    if(popupStatus==0){
        $("#backgroundPopup").css({
            "opacity": "0.7"
        }).fadeIn("slow");

        $contact_selector.fadeIn("fast");

        popupStatus = 1;
    }
}
//disabling popup with jQuery magic!
function disablePopup($contact_selector){
    //disables popup only if it is enabled
    if(popupStatus==1){
        $("#backgroundPopup").fadeOut("slow");
        $contact_selector.fadeOut("slow");
        popupStatus = 0;
    }
}

    //centering popup
    function centerPopup($contact_selector){
        //request data for centering
        var windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
        var windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        var popupHeight = $("body").height();
        var popupWidth = $("body").width();
        //centering
        $contact_selector.css({
            "position": "absolute",
            "top": windowHeight/2-popupHeight/2,
            "left": windowWidth/2-popupWidth/2
        });
        //only need force for IE6

        $("#backgroundPopup").css({
            "height": windowHeight
        });

    }

    $(document).ready(function(){   
        //LOADING POPUP
        //Click the button event!
        $("#button1").click(function(){
            //centering with css
            centerPopup($('#popupContact1'));
            //load popup
            loadPopup($('#popupContact1'));
        });
        $("#button2").click(function(){
            //centering with css
            centerPopup($('#popupContact2'));
            //load popup
            loadPopup($('#popupContact2'));
        });
        $("#button3").click(function(){
            //centering with css
            centerPopup($('#popupContact3'));
            //load popup
            loadPopup($('#popupContact3'));
        });
        $("#button4").click(function(){
            //centering with css
            centerPopup($('#popupContact4'));
            //load popup
            loadPopup($('#popupContact4'));
        }); 
        $("#button5").click(function(){
            //centering with css
            centerPopup($('#popupContact5'));
            //load popup
            loadPopup($('#popupContact5'));
        });
        $("#button6").click(function(){
            //centering with css
            centerPopup($('#popupContact6'));
            //load popup
            loadPopup($('#popupContact6'));
        });                 
        //CLOSING POPUP
        //Click the x event!
        $("#popupContactClose1").click(function(){
        disablePopup($('#popupContact1'));
    });
        $("#popupContactClose2").click(function(){
        disablePopup($('#popupContact2'));
    });
        $("#popupContactClose3").click(function(){
        disablePopup($('#popupContact3'));
    });
        $("#popupContactClose4").click(function(){
        disablePopup($('#popupContact4'));
    });
        $("#popupContactClose5").click(function(){
        disablePopup($('#popupContact5'));
    });
        $("#popupContactClose6").click(function(){
        disablePopup($('#popupContact6'));
    });

    $("#backgroundPopup").click(function(){  
    disablePopup($('.popup'));  
    }); 

        //Press Escape event!
        $(document).keyup(function(e) {
        if( e.which == 27 ){
        disablePopup($('.popup'));

        }
    });
    });
```

and finally the css: this is also a bit irrelevant but helps to show how the jquery works

```
#backgroundPopup{  
display:none;  
position:fixed;  
_position:absolute; /* hack for internet explorer 6*/  
height:100%;  
width:100%;  
top:0;  
left:0;  
background:#000000;  
border:1px solid #cecece;  
z-index:1;  
}  
#popupContact1, #popupContact2, #popupContact3, #popupContact4, #popupContact5, #popupContact6{  
display:none;  
position:fixed;  
_position:absolute; /* hack for internet explorer 6*/  
height:400px;  
width:420px;  
background:#eee76f;  
border:2px solid black;  
z-index:2;  
padding:12px;  
font-size:13px;  
border-radius: 15px;
}  

.popup{
    overflow:auto;
}

.show_hide{
    float:left;
}
#popupContact1 h1, #popupContact2 h1, #popupContact3 h1, #popupContact4 h1, #popupContact5 h1, #popupContact6 h1{  
text-align:left;  
color:black;  
font-size:22px;  
font-weight:700;  
border-bottom:1px dotted black;  
padding-bottom:2px;  
margin-bottom:20px;  
}  
#popupContactClose1, #popupContactClose2, #popupContactClose3,#popupContactClose4,#popupContactClose5,#popupContactClose6{  
font-size:14px;  
line-height:14px;  
right:6px;  
top:4px;  
position:absolute;  
color:black;  
font-weight:700;  
display:block;  
cursor:pointer;
}  
#button6,#button5,#button4,#button3,#button2,#button1 {  
text-align:left;  
cursor:pointer;
width:150px;
}
```

please let me know if there is anything else I should have included

thank you

snackerfish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is perfect [ajax functions](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) in jQuery. For your case you can use something like

```
$('#recipe_cont').load('/recipe/123/ajax/')
```

Actually you should use one URL for both ajax and non-ajax access but it's easier to separate them for learning. `/recipe/123/ajax/` will return just part of the page, `<div id="recipe">...</div>` with all recipe content.

That's it. You can also add client side caching and other stuff, but basically this would work fine enough.

Comment: this is perfect but i believe i should use the popupContact div instead. Would it be smart to have only one popupContact div and add recipes to that container?

Comment: As you wish - you can add containers and cache data inside them that way. But most simple solution is to have one container and load data into it every time. So yes, you can use your popup for it.

Comment: in the url /recipe/123/ajax is the 123 the recipe number or is that necessary for ajax

Comment: Sure, it's the recipe ID. Actually, you can use any URL you like as long as it routes to the correct view. There's no any URL naming conventions for AJAX calls.

Comment: how can i load different things depending on what I click?

for instance say i have a link and when i click that link i want content to load in the popupdiv is this possible?

Comment: Every link has a `href`, you can use it with `$(this).attr('href')` in click handler